# Как решить проблему с документом word 7й версии?

Tags: ms-word

Открываю документ Word и он через пару секунд закрывается самостоятельно. Стоит операционная система Windows 7.
На ноутбуке с Windows 10 и с тем же пакетом офис, ситуация немного лучше закрывается, если в документ добавляешь данные.
Оба компьютера имеют защиту *касперского* и ранее проблем не наблюдалось.

*Сигнатура проблемы:*
 - Имя события проблемы: APPCRASH

- Имя приложения: WINWORD.EXE
- Версия приложения: 12.0.4528.1014
- Штамп времени приложения: 45428029
- Имя модуля с ошибкой: ntdll.dll
- Версия модуля с ошибкой: 6.0.6000.16396
- Штамп времени модуля с ошибкой: 4549bdc9
- Код исключения: c0000006
- Смещение исключения: 00022a7f
- Код языка: 1049
- Дополнительные сведения 1: c453
- Дополнительные сведения 2: abcc8f7853b48d9807d6d51eb1fa5df9
- Дополнительные сведения 3: c453
- Дополнительные сведения 4: abcc8f7853b48d9807d6d51eb1fa5df9

Comment: Пересохранение в каком-нибудь другом формате ничего не дает? Может быть открыть через Open office? Ну или открыть, все выделить, запихнуть в чистый документ и посмотреть что выйдет.

Answer (score 2):

В первую очередь это системная ошибка.

1. Отсутствие необходимых библиотек   -NET framework., DirectX.,Visual
   C++ будет не лишним обновить и Microsoft   XNA Framework.
2. Обновления системы Если же автоматическое обновление отключено, то стоит установить [пакет исправлений](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/2541119/applications-may-crash-in-windows-vista--in-windows-7--in-windows-serv) вручную.
3. Повреждение системных файлов Команда проверки целостности системных файлов: **sfc /scannow**
4. Проблемы совместимости Можно попробовать выбрать предыдущие версии Windows, а также включить галочку «Запускать эту программу от имени администратора».
5. Блокировка библиотек защитой Кроме этого стоит обратить внимание на защитную функцию самой Windows, которая называется DEP (англ. Data Execution Prevention — Предотвращение выполнения данных) Можно попробовать отключить данную защиту и если ошибка исчезнет, то следует добавить программу или игру в исключения DEP («Система» -> «Дополнительные параметры системы» -> «Дополнительно» -> «Быстродействие» -> «Параметры» -> «Предотвращение выполнения данных»).
6. Драйвера устройств
7. Реестр Windows
8. Когда ничего не помогает… [пробуйте](https://onlinefilerepair.com/ru/rtf-repair-online.html) microsoft word исправить путем поиска на других сайтах и не стесняйтесь пользоваться поисковиком.
9. Обновляйте защитное ПО и изучите справки пакета офис.